# Angular query-parameters with unknown params before

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string

is it possible pass any params in ui-router?

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters

url: "/contacts?myParams..."

I don't know all parameter previously

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? As you've linked, ui-router does manage URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

i solved using a single param

```
    .state('auth.print_customers', {
     url: '/print_customers?filter'
      ...
```

with

```
$state.href('print_customers', {filter: angular.toJson($scope.tableParams.$params.filter)});﻿
```